# Initializing structs in C++

Tags: c++, struct

As an addendum to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837854/initializing-an-object-to-all-zeroes), what is going on here:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    string s;
};

int main() {
    A a = {0};
}
```

Obviously, you can't set a std::string to zero. Can someone provide an explanation (backed with references to the C++ Standard, please) about what is actually supposed to happen here? And then explain for example):

```
int main() {
    A a = {42};
}
```

Are either of these well-defined?

Once again an embarrassing question for me - I always give my structs constructors, so the issue has never arisen before.

Comment: The `boost::array` class template is an aggregate too. So you can do `array<std::string, 2> a = { "foo", "bar" };` with it, for example. Also, my lazy-construct-array is an aggregate too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662417/c-suppress-automatic-initialization-and-destruction/2662526#2662526

Comment: Implicit conversions + aggregates...

ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @litb when I first saw that feature of `boost::array` I had an enlightenment, AKA sexual-satisfaction-of-the-brain. Simple things that make so much sense tend to do that to me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your struct is an *aggregate*, so the ordinary rules for aggregate initialization work for it. The process is described in 8.5.1. Basically the whole 8.5.1 is dedicated to it, so I don't see the reason to copy the whole thing here. The general idea is virtually the same it was in C, just adapted to C++: you take an initializer from the right, you take a member from the left and you initialize the member with that initializer. According to 8.5/12, this shall be a *copy-initialization*.

When you do

```
A a = { 0 };
```

you are basically copy-initializing `a.s` with `0`, i.e. for `a.s` it is semantically equivalent to

```
string s = 0;
```

The above compiles because `std::string` is convertible from a `const char *` pointer. (And it is undefined behavior, since null pointer is not a valid argument in this case.)

Your `42` version will not compile for the very same reason the

```
string s = 42;
```

will not compile. `42` is not a null pointer constant, and `std::string` has no means for conversion from `int` type.

**P.S.** Just in case: note that the definition of *aggregate* in C++ is not recursive (as opposed to the definition of POD, for example). `std::string` is not an aggregate, but it doesn't change anything for your `A`. `A` is still an aggregate.

Comment: §12.6.1 is also relevant, as noted in § 8.5.1 13.

Comment: @outis: I looked through 12.6.1 and I couldn't immediately see what it added to what was already in 8.5. Every time 12.6.1 deals with aggregate initialization, it seems to refer back to 8.5 :)

Comment: It's interesting to see that in `basic_string(size_type n, charT c, const Allocator a=Allocator())` there's a reason why `size_type n` doesn't have a default value. The reason is that it's a bad idea to overload on a pointer and an integer. The value 0 (zero) is strictly an integer, not a pointer, and so you wouldn't be able to construct through the pointer overload with a null pointer, unless of course you'd cast explicitly. The standard avoids this confusion by requiring a character type if you specify a string length at string construction.

Comment: it specifies when class members of an aggregate are copy-initialized, value-initialized or that the initializer is ill-formed.

Answer (score 8):

8.5.1/12 "Aggregates" says:

> All implicit type conversions (clause 4) are considered when initializing the aggregate member with an initializer from an initializer-list.

So

```
A a = {0};
```

will get initialized with a NULL `char*` (as [AndreyT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838107/initialising-structs-in-c/2838133#2838133) and [Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838107/initialising-structs-in-c/2838120#2838120) indicated), and

```
A a = {42};
```

will fail at compile time since there's no implicit conversion that'll match up with a `std::string` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

**0 is a null pointer constant**

S.4.9:

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to
>   zero.

**A null pointer constant can be converted to any other pointer type:**

S.4.9:

> A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that
>   type

**What you gave for the definition of `A` is considered an aggregate:**

S.8.5.1:

> An aggregate is an array or a class with no user-declared constructors, no private or protected
>   non-static data members, no base classes, and no virtual functions.

**You are specifying an initializer clause:**

S.8.5.1:

> When an aggregate is initialized the initializer can contain an initializer-clause consisting of a brace enclosed,
>   comma-separated list of initializer-clauses for the members of the aggregate

**`A` contains a member of the aggregate of type `std::string`, and the initializer clause applies to it.**

**Your aggregate is copy-initialized**

> When an aggregate (whether class or array) contains members of class type and is initialized by a brace enclosed
>   initializer-list, each such member is copy-initialized.

**Copy initializing means that you have the equivalent to `std::string s = 0` or `std::string s = 42`;**

S.8.5-12

> The initialization that occurs in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception (15.1), handling
>   an exception (15.3), and brace-enclosed initializer lists (8.5.1) is called copy-initialization and is equivalent
>   to the form T x = a;

**`std::string s = 42` will not compile because there is no implicit conversion, `std::string s = 0` will compile (because an implicit conversion exists) but results in undefined behavior.**

`std::string`'s constructor for `const char*` is not defined as `explicit` which means you can do this:  `std::string s = 0`

Just to show that things are actually being copy-initialized, you could do this simple test:

```
class mystring
{
public:

  explicit mystring(const char* p){}
};

struct A {
  mystring s;
};


int main()
{
    //Won't compile because no implicit conversion exists from const char*
    //But simply take off explicit above and everything compiles fine.
    A a = {0};
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As people have pointed out, this "works" because string has a constructor that can take 0 as a parameter. If we say:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    map <int,int> m;
};

int main() {
    A a = {0};
}
```

then we get a compilation error, as the map class does not have such a constructor.

Comment: Why is your pic avatar not shown in this answer? Is it hidden on community answers?

Comment: @Johannes A mystery! Do you want to report it as a bug on meta or shall I?

Comment: Your identity doesn't belong to you, it belongs to the Collective.

Answer (score 1):

In 21.3.1/9 the standard forbids the `char*` argument of the relevant constructor of a `std::basic_string` from being a null pointer. This should throw a `std::logic_error`, but I have yet to see where in the standard is the guarantee that violating a precondition throws a `std::logic_error`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, violating a precondition guarantees undefined behavior, not an exception.

Comment: @James g++ 4.0.1 on OS X 10.5.8 throws a `std::logic_error` at construction time. 19.1.1 says this is what `logic_error` is for, but I can't find a guarantee this is what happens when there's a violation of an invariant or precondition.