# Is it reasonable to codify lazy loading as a template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, lazy-loading

I'm wondering if something like

```
template <typename T>
class LazyLoaded
{
    mutable char mem[sizeof T]; //First item in the class to keep alignment issues at bay
    const std::function<void (T&)> initializer;
    mutable bool loaded;
public:
    LazyLoaded() : loaded(false)
    {
        initializer = [] (T&) {};
    }
    LazyLoaded(const std::function<void (T&)>& init) : initializer(init), loaded(false)
    {
    }
    T& Get()
    {
        if (!loaded)
        {
            new (static_cast<void *>(&mem)) T();
            initializer(*static_cast<T*>(&mem));
            loaded = true;
        }
        return *static_cast<T*>(&mem);
    }
    ~LazyLoaded()
    {
        if (loaded)
        {
            static_cast<T*>(&mem)->~T();
        }
    }
};
```

is possible or makes sense to do. (I think there are issues with this code, but hey, I threw it together in 10 minutes, so....)

Comment: Why do you mess around with placement new and delete? You could just use ordinary new and delete and manage the T instance with a pointer or a smart pointer.

Comment: `std::aligned_storage` is a better solution for alignment.  I don't think `char[]` is completely correct here.

Comment: Why are the array and the boolean `mutable`? I don't see you modifying either in a `const` member function.

Comment: @Praetorian: I think that `Get` is supposed to be `const`.

Comment: @James: `alignas(T)` should be used with a `char[]`.  Punning between `aligned_storage` and `T` would be illegal, no?

Comment: I think this class would fit well into the family with [this class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662417/c-suppress-automatic-initialization-and-destruction/2662526#2662526)!

Comment: @BenVoigt Placement new takes a `void*` so `new (&storage) T()` doesn't break rules I believe.

Comment: @Luc: Ok, I think you're right there.  Still think that `alignas` is a better approach.

Comment: @Ben:  Oh; I wasn't aware that an `alignas` specifier was added; nifty.

Comment: @James: section 7.6.2 `[dcl.align]`

Comment: @user: Because normal new and delete incur dynamic memory allocation overhead.

Comment: @Billy: Since you're calling the default constructor anyway, you could just have a member of type `T`.  But `boost::optional` does solve the value storage nicely; I don't see how it helps with lazy execution.

Comment: @Ben: I don't want to call the default constructor until `Get` is first called (with the assumption that the default constructor might be expensive). If I just store a `T` then the default constructor is called when the `LazyLoaded` is constructed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/index.html). This should provide almost all the necessary functionality.